# Combine multiple requests in helidon

Tags: rest, helidon

Is there any way I can combine multiple rest requests in single http call using helidon? Something similar to below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching

I tried doing in similar way as mentioned in above doc but getting 400. Below is my json format.

````
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/parent/123"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/parent/123/child/availableChildRecords"
    },
    {
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
      }
  ]
} ```
````

Comment: Please, could you post a complete excerpt from your source code to better understand what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

The page you've [referenced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching) is describing an API of a specific service - [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/) in this case. The capability to combine the multiple HTTP requests is **not** part of the HTTP protocol. To support a similar capability in your application, you have to build it yourself.